# The usage of "le pays de..."

Tags: sens, expressions

I came across the following sentence in *Le Petit Prince*:

> C’est tellement mystérieux, **le pays des larmes**.

From the context, as well as from what my intuition tells me, I think that **le pays de...** should mean something similar to: *the world of...*

In this sentence that would be:

> It's very mysterious, the world of tears.

Then I realized that the noun *pays* is used (and not the use of the word *monde* for example), so the literal meaning would be:

the country of tears?

Is this the general case in French language, that the word *pays* is used for that purpose?

Is the expression **le pays de...** used in French in exactly the same context, as you would use **the world of...** in English? Could you for instance use it to say things like: the world of opportunities, the world of mystery, etc.?

Can you give me some examples of other usages of **le pays de...** in a sentence?

Comment: "The world of" seems very planet-ey to me, it's a little too much for a region of the worlds. I see "le pays de" as a chronological evolution of "the kingdom of" or "the realm of". I can't think of a non-medieval term but the meaning is more region-like than world-like.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: My country, officially Kingdom of the Netherlands, is called "Les Pays-Bas" in French.

Comment: @Kevin but it's the term "Nether**land**s" that translate to "Pays-Bas", not the Kingdom part. The official french name in the long form is indeed "Royaume des Pays-Bas".

Comment: If you translate *pays* with *land* instead of *country* the examples make sense in English as well: the land of tears, the land of opportunity. Of course, land isn't used (anymore?) in English to literally refer to countries, but it does seem to have an etymology in that direction, as evidenced by several of the examples on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/land#Noun).

Comment: @Jasper - well, we have the Nether**land**s, Ire**land**, Scot**land** and, of course, Eng**land** as countries, and Jut**land** (or Jyland in Denmark) and Rut**land** as regions...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This expression would be used in french to describe a place where something is plentiful, or from where something originates.

Off the top of my head an example is France sometimes being referred to as

> le pays des droits de l'Homme

in reference to France's historical role in human rights.

However, as in the example you provided, "le pays" does not have to refer to an actual country, and can just refer to an area or even abstract poetic concepts.

For instance, sleep is sometimes called

> le pays des rêves

Furthermore, many children's books may refer to "au pays des géants" or such examples, referring to some land containing giants.

In terms of translating it, I would use the expression "the land of" as opposed to "the world of".

Common expressions are "the land of the free", to talk about the United States, "the land of the rising sun" to talk about Japan, or "the land of giants" to refer to my above example.

In terms of other usages of "le pays":

- at its most basic, just means "the country"

  > L'Espagne, c'est le pays où je vais le plus souvent en vacances.
- sometimes can refer to where someone is from

  > Je retourne au pays => I'm going back to my hometown/home area
- can be used to describe visiting the country side/various parts of a country

  > Le week-end dernier, je suis allé voir du pays

Comment: Thanks! Do you then also use in French an expression that would be closer to English the world of..., like le monde de...? Can you give me some examples?

Comment: "le monde de" is a valid expression and everyone will understand what you are saying. For example, Finding Nemo was called "Le monde de Nemo", literally "the world of Nemo". You could also use it to talk about fields, such as "entrer dans le monde de la politique", which would mean entering politics/the field of politics/the world of politics.

Comment: Okay! I see the difference now. Just as a comment: after reading your explanation I think I would chose to say _le monde de larmes_, rather than _le pays de larmes_. The example you've given: _le pays des rêves_, is indeed more of a poetic concept, however it does express that when you fall asleep you enter a different **place**... But tears here are more of a concept then a place. At least that's how I feel this sentence :)

Comment: English uses the word “country” with a non-nation meaning too. “Land” is a good translation, but it might be helpful to the asker to point out these non-nation uses of “country” as an intuitive comparison to dilute the ideas *pays* only means nation-state. Consider [“We can't stop here, this is bat country!”](https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/1309111-fear-and-loathing-in-las-vegas-a-savage-journey-to-the-heart-of-the-ame) (which isn't saying it's a nation-state of bats, just a geographical region of plentiful bats). We also see it in phrases like “We went for a walk in the country.”

Comment: Yes very good point and reference

Comment: @Camille If you translate "pays" by "world" in Saint Expury's *le pays des larmes* you miss the whole emotional concept that "land" carries and that "world" (more neutral) does not convey.

Answer (score 9):

*Pays* translates the English word "land"<sup>1</sup> in

> le pays des larmes...

Lewis Carrol's *Alice's Adventures in Wonder**land*** has been translated into French as *Les Aventures d'Alice au **pays** des merveilles*.

The various translations  of *Le Petit Prince* I have consulted all translate

> C’est tellement mystérieux, le pays des larmes.

as

> It is such a mysterious place, the land of tears.[[eg]](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/the-little-prince)

Laurent PetitGirard's piece of ballet music *Le Pays des larmes* for *Le Petit Prince* has retained [the translation](http://www.allmusic.com/album/laurent-petitgirard-the-little-prince-mw0002557929) "The Land of Tears".

To respond to OP's comment to @NicoMezeret that "tears here are more of a concept then a place", I'll point to the song by English singer Julian Cope "[When I Walk Through the Land of Fear](http://www.thelyricarchive.com/song/579429-78219/When-I-Walk-Through-the-Land-of-Fear)", where there is no reference to a place whatsoever, but to a state of mind.

"Land" is used in place of "country" when the word refers not to the political, administrative or geographical entity but to an emotional one. Let's think of "the Land of Plenty" to designate the US (Film by Wim Wenders), "Land of Fear" to designate here [a district of Cairo](http://www.dailynewsegypt.com/2015/01/28/volatile-matariya-braces-protests/), "land of fear and loathing" used [here](http://www.heraldscotland.com/news/14566298.In_England_____a_land_of_fear_and_loathing/) for England.

A popular catchphrase nowadays is *au pays des bisounours*<sup>2</sup>. *Le pays des bisounours* being a land peopled with rather dumb-witted and gullible creatures.

> [Alain Juppé veut prouver qu'il "ne vit pas au pays des Bisounours"](http://www.lexpress.fr/actualite/politique/lr/alain-juppe-veut-prouver-qu-il-ne-vit-pas-au-pays-des-bisounours_1750083.html)
>
> [Cyberattaque : l'édition vit-elle au pays des Bisounours ?](https://www.actualitte.com/article/monde-edition/cyberattaque-l-edition-vit-elle-au-pays-des-bisounours/62429)

<sup>1 See [wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/land#Noun) definition 7.</sup>
<sup>2 *Les Bisounours*: The Care Bears.</sup>